# Are there limitations on using multiple CASE statements across multiple UNIONs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, union

Nice simple question, no sql code needed, just your knowledge regarding precedence.

In one of my common table expressions I have 5 unions, in the SELECT statement there are three columns, Col1, Col2 and Col3 (Example). All three of these fields have a CASE WHEN statement on them but with varying operators and conditions (It's why I have so many UNION's, as if two WHEN statements are TRUE, SQl server will pick the first one so I'm appending the additional rows if another condition is TRUE). Below is an example

```
Select CASE WHEN a.Co1<>b.Col1 THEN a.Col
from Table A
UNION    
Select CASE WHEN a.Co1=b.Col1 THEN b.Col
from Table A    
UNION   
Select CASE WHEN a.Co1<>b.Col1 THEN a.Col
from Table A    
UNION  
Select CASE WHEN a.Co1<>b.Col1 and col3 = 'A Value' THEN a.Col
from Table A    
UNION   
Select CASE WHEN a.Co1=b.Col1 and col3 = 'A Value' THEN a.Col
from Table A
```

Are there limitations and pitfalls I have to be aware of? Since I was already caught of guard with CASE statements having more than one TRUE outcome. I also know that in UNIONs only the first referenced col names are used. I ask, because my values I get are not adhering to the CASE statement so I'm wondering if having multiple cases on the same col across multiple union statements is conflicting or problematic for SQL Server to resolve. I figured, that each query between the UNION's will simply just append if a record is receive, well... here's hoping.

Comment: Where would `b.Col` be coming from?  I would expect to see a `JOIN` or correlation between `A` and `B` tables.

Comment: How close to real is your example?  Your 3rd block looks identical to the first block.  The 4th block is no different than the first block (returning the same column).  Also, rows that evaluate true for `a.Co1<>b.Col1 and col3 = 'A Value'` will also evaluate true for the first block (`a.Co1<>b.Col1`).

Comment: Give us an example of what you mean by 'not adhering to the CASE statement.'  A good format is "here is what I get" <example>, but "here is what I want" <example>. By the way, should you actually be using UNION ALL instead of UNION (UNION removes duplicates)?

Comment: Tradition demands an `END` for each `CASE`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, now to answer. 1) @Goat CO the A and B is a result of a self join, your right I should have included that but I'm not querying the syntax, just simply if there are implications if several different Case statements on the same column, across a spread of UNIONs had unwanted or unexpected outcomes. An example was the mention of precedence in CASES if two conditions resulted as TRUE.

Comment: @Andrew very far from the real code I've typed, I was hoping I could verbally explain if there are "things" I need to watch out for and consider in sql server. Yes I was typing this example free hand and making up conditions, apologies for the dups. I think this question would be simply better with a proper example, as this is what the community is used to.

Comment: @JonBoulineau I'll post a real example later via fiddle or paste in some data for you to copy out. hmm not really, I know the rows are going to be unique anyway so I've stuck to UNION, unless without me checking the execution plan later, is there a performance difference?

Comment: @HABO very true, and my code does have this. I'll create a real example, as this seems this what this question really needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your example what your actual logic is, but if you are actually pulling from the same table multiple times with varying conditions then you could likely reduce the number of table scans by combining mutually exclusive conditions together, for example the top 2 conditions are mutually exclusive, and could be combined into one scan:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.Co1<>b.Col1 THEN a.Col 
            ELSE b.Col 
       END
FROM  Table_1 a
JOIN  Table_2 b
  ON a.ID = b.SomeID 
UNION 
SELECT CASE WHEN a.Co1<>b.Col1 and col3 = 'A Value' THEN a.Col 
            WHEN col3 = 'A Value' THEN a.Col 
       END
FROM  Table_3 a
JOIN  Table_4 b
  ON a.ID = b.SomeID
```

And leverage `UNION` with `ALL` when possible for performance, I can't post the two words next to each other due to firewall restriction.

Comment: Very interesting, This is what I originally did but couldn't get it to work. Example soon, maybe your insight can get it to work and reduce the number of table scans

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a union just to apply different case logic? You can combine it into one case statement (you would just need to put the most limiting case first), something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN a.Co1 = b.Col1 and col3 = 'A Value' THEN a.Col
   WHEN a.Co1 <> b.Col1 and col3 = 'A Value' THEN a.Col
   WHEN a.Co1 <> b.Col1 THEN a.Col 
   WHEN a.Co1 = b.Col1 THEN b.Col
END
FROM Table A
```

Comment: Yes that's why I'm using the UNION, even with different operators I have to use it as I'm tracking changes across multiple fields in two columns, one CurrentValue and one Previous Value. If more than one field is changed I can't track this in one row so I need to append